# Monitoring disk read/write activity

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to get current disk loading using python?

I use psutil to get CPU and RAM usage (`psutil.cpu_percent()` and `psutil.virtual_memory().used`) but I don't know how to get data like this about HDD.

Something like `Disk in/out: XX MB/s` and `Disk active time: XX%` like in Windows resources monitor (I'm using Windows by the way) would be great.

Comment: I just found this: https://www.tecmint.com/iotop-monitor-linux-disk-io-activity-per-process/ maybe helpful.

Comment: @walker As I wrote I use Windows not Linux

Comment: psutil.disk_io_counters(perdisk=False) ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/5.2.2 )

Comment: @Claudio Yes it could be computed this way. I just wonder if there is easiest way.