# See Disk Activity In Python

Tags: python, disk, hard-drive

Is there a python command or library that I can call to see if hard drive is being written to or read from?

Like this C# one
[Detect if hard disk is being accessed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242203/detect-if-hard-disk-is-being-accessed-or-not)

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864894/monitoring-disk-read-write-activity

Answer (score 3):

Answered above by Nathan Liang

[Monitoring disk read/write activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864894/monitoring-disk-read-write-activity)

The answer is at
https://pypi.org/project/psutil/5.2.2/

The call would be based on

```
import psutil
print(psutil.disk_io_counters(perdisk=False))
```

giving the output something like this

> sdiskio(read_count=719566, write_count=1082197,
> read_bytes=18626220032, write_bytes=24081764352, read_time=5023392,
> write_time=63199568, read_merged_count=619166,
> write_merged_count=812396, busy_time=4523412)

to see busy time is

```
import psutil
psutil.disk_io_counters(perdisk=False)
print(psutil.disk_io_counters(perdisk=False).busy_time)
```